# Analytic Grothendieck Riemann Roch

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory, topological-k-theory

I was wandering if is there an analytic version of the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem. If so, could you please tell me the references?

Comment: I like your misspelling ... "Grothendieck Riemann Rock", the new music for mathematicians.

Comment: Well, that's indeed embarrassing, but I think was an automatic correction of my computer. Anyhow, I corrected. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Also, in the title all hyphens are missing, but who cares:)